# Which of the line segments $a, b, c, d, e$ of the diagonal is the longest?

Tags: geometry, logic

A question given to me, by my teacher. I can't understand this. Maybe a logical geometry problem?

> A square with area $30$ is split into two by its diagonal and then
> split into triangles as shown in the diagram. Some of the areas of the triangles are given in the diagram. Which of the line segments $a, b, c, d, e$ of the diagonal is the longest?

[image]

Comment: I believe it can be either $d$ or $c$ for simple aplication of the formula $S = \frac{ab \cdot \sin (\angle C)}2$ you can say like: $a:2 = (a+b):5$ so $b>a$ and so on.

Comment: i didnt understand

Comment: @PulkitSabharwal: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Your teacher probably gave you this exercise thinking it would be a nice challenge, and may well be disappointed that you simply gave it to the internet to solve for you. Be that as it may ... You could help us help you by telling us something of what you know abut the problem, so that we don't waste time (ours or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques above your current level. For starters: Can you fill-in the missing areas? And what ways of *calculating* area do you know that might be helpful here?

Comment: Yes i can fill in the missing areas and i know trigonometric ways of calculating area

Comment: Can you add to your post what you've done so far? A HINT: Areas of triangles with same height are proportional to their base.

Comment: Well , i tried what hellofriends's suggested . I used the formula , area of triangle = ab.sin(c)*1/2 . From that  i could know the values of a , b , c , d , e.  For eg - for the triangle with area 2 . 2 = sin 45 * root 30 * a * 1/2 . So i tried this . But i think there is a more logical solution

Comment: @PulkitSabharwal: ACB's hint will get you there. It leverages the fact that the area of a triangle is $\frac12\cdot\text{base}\cdot\text{height}$. (In this case, all the triangles can be viewed as having the same height.) ... Anyway, please [edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4350090/edit) to add your work and thoughts there. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden (or moved elsewhere).

Comment: I found the answer , it is that d is the longest side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the rule , in a triangle , the area of a triangle can be expressed as sin ab * angle c * 1/2 .

2 = sin 45 ( the diagonal of square cuts 90 degree into 2 equal parts) * root 30 ( area of square is 30 so side is root 30 ) * a * 1/2 = 1/ root 2 * root 30 * a * 1/2 = root 15 /2 a

root 15 a = 4
a = 4/root 15

similarily applying the rule to other triangles we find that b = 6 / root 15 , d = 10 / root 15 and  e = 8 / root 15 . The value of c can be found out by applying the pythagoras theorem . The length of the diagonal of this square is root 60 and c = length of the diagonal - length of other segments (a,b,d,e) which is equal to

root 60 - 28 / root 15 = (15 root 60 - 28 root 15)/15 = (30 root 15 -28 root 15)/15 = (2 root 15)/15. Then by rationalizating the values of all other segments (a,b,d,e) and then by comparing , we find that d is the longest.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).